# How to compile code with MinGW

Tags: c, windows, batch-file, compilation, mingw

I just installed MinGW and tried to compile my (incomplete) code using a bat file that has the line 'gcc-o outputname.exe inputcode.c glut32.lib-lglu32-lopengl32'. All this does is create a tmp file name txxxxx.tmp (trz8EFF.tmp for example) instead of the executable. I have my PATH variable connected to the folder containing gcc, and I'm running the bat from a separate folder from minGW which has the glut library in it. I don't think anything went wrong with installation of minGW so not sure what the problem is. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Cheers

Comment: can you compile and run simple stuff?

Comment: Also, I don't like the non-spaces before the dashes, but maybe that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gcc -o outputname.exe inputcode.c -static -Lpath_to_lib -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32
```